# Filter Data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have an excel data which contains iterations data of each time step in a simulation. I want to take the values of only the last iteration in a time step, see image below.
How can I set up a filter for that in Excel? I have already read [this](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-formula-for-filtering-data/), however this only gives the values which have a specific value. How can I tell excel I want the last row which meets a specific criterion.

[image]

Comment: I edited the image.

Answer (score 2):

a quick and simple way to do this involves adding in a new column C called something like IsMax. In here you can have a formula to find out the max Coefficient for the given Accumulated.

Something like this could work, assuming this is being typed into C2

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)=B2
```

This would return TRUE only for the rows you want

[image: Excel screenshot showing mock up of Accumulated and Coefficient values with a new column showing TRUE or FALSE to flag the appropriate rows]

Answer (score -1):

To quickly locate and select all cells that contain a particular sort of data, such as formulae, use the Go To command. Use Go To to narrow your search results to just the cells that match your requirements, like as the final cell on the worksheet with any data or formatting.

Comment: It apparently does not have the option for the filtering that I want

Comment: @Vahid in past i got same problem i resolved it on this way , but i didn't know why its not working on your problem